# How do I select a standard app for PDF?

Tags: windows-10, file-types

I want to select a certain app to open PDF.

However, when I search "Standard programs", and I find "PDF" and click it, I can not select my own app.

Instead, Windows only offers these:

[image]

Comment: Is the `certain app` already installed on your system?

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on any .PDF file.
2. Select *Open with > Choose another app*.
3. If you do not see your favorite, e.g., *Okular* or *Sumatra*, **scroll down the list**.
4. If you still don't see it, select *More apps* , and find the application.
5. Click *Always use this app to open .pdf files*.
6. Click *OK*.

[image: Open with dlg]